# Limit to Flex P2P connection for live video chat?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, video-streaming, p2p

If one person starts broadcasting a P2P live video chat, how many viewers can connect to this broadcaster? Is there a limit to the amount of viewers who can connect to a single broadcaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you read more into the [technology](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/).  My understanding is that there is no 'software' limits to the amount of people that view the video chat through RTMFP groups because each person that views the video will also broadcast it to the next person to reduce the load on the original broadcaster.

Of course, if the bandwidth isn't present, some people might not be able to see the video or won't have good quality.